# Cloud Endpoints generate entity key inside of Android/iOS client libs

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way inside of Android Java to create an Entity Key?

For example, inside the Cloud Endpoints Java module code you can do this:

```
Key<User> userKey= Key.create(User.class, userId);
```

or with an Ancestor:

```
Key<Post> postKey= Key.create(userKey, Post.class, postId);
```

How can you do the above in the Android generated client library? I want to see if I can create a key in Android and pass it to an API method (probably as a websafeKey `userKey.getString()`).

**BONUS**: How can you do this with the objective-C Cloud Endpoints client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you want either the datastore nor objectify code in your Android App. That simply not where that belongs. So the way to go is to look at the source of the [KeyFactory](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.java). In the method `keyToString()` we can see that most of the magic happens in the class [KeyTranslator](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyTranslator.java) in method `convertToPb()`.

Here's the code of convertToPb:

```
public static Reference convertToPb(Key key) {
    Reference reference = new Reference();

    reference.setApp(key.getAppId());
    String nameSpace = key.getNamespace();
    if (!nameSpace.isEmpty()) {
        reference.setNameSpace(nameSpace);
    }

    Path path = reference.getMutablePath();
    while (key != null) {
        Element pathElement = new Element();
        pathElement.setType(key.getKind());
        if (key.getName() != null) {
            pathElement.setName(key.getName());
        } else if (key.getId() != Key.NOT_ASSIGNED) {
            pathElement.setId(key.getId());
        }
        path.addElement(pathElement);
        key = key.getParent();
    }
    Collections.reverse(path.mutableElements());
    return reference;
}
```

And here's the code of keyToString()

```
public static String keyToString(Key key) {
    if (!key.isComplete()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key is incomplete.");
    } else {
        Reference reference = KeyTranslator.convertToPb(key);
        return base64Url().omitPadding().encode(reference.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Now what you want to do, is to replace the Key stuff in convertToPb with "normal" parameters (type, name/key, parent type, parent name/key) and thus rewrite the method to create a websafeKey without an actual `Key` object.

It would be much easier though if your app engine API simply accepted the ids and you'd recreate the key on the appengine side of things. My APIs are usually structured like

```
/user/<userId>/post/<postId>
```

if i assume an Entity that looks like this

```
@Entity public class Post {
@Parent Ref<User> user
@Id id; }
```

**Regarding the bonus:** What (the heck) is an Objectify Cloud Endpoint? I know Cloud Endpoints and Objectify, but i have not heard of a product that combines the two.

Comment: Fixed the bonus typo - I meant "objective-c" not "objectify" lol. Cloud Endpoints can generate objective-c iphone client libs. Regarding your comment "It would be much easier though if your app engine API simply accepted the ids and you'd recreate the key on the appengine side of things." That works and I do do that when the entity has no parent. However, if the entity has a parent, I would also need to pass in the parent ID to the API method to say, delete it. In my Android/iOS app it seems troublesome to pass that extra information around since it is one level up in say, a tableview.

Comment: I know, we discussed this. It's a fact though that you could simply put the ids of all ancestors in the request url (as you can see in the code sample above the websafeKey does the same, with much more overhead). I just said it for anyone else reading this. Hm for objective-c i guess you could implement an objective-c version of convertToPb.

Comment: That's not a bad idea: "you could simply put the ids of all ancestors in the request url". I could just store the the parentId in the child Entity in addition to storing the parentKey annotated with `@Parent` (which is required in Cloud Endpoints). An unencrypted `websafeKey` also contains information like google app engine project-id if you decode it so that is probably something you wouldn't want someone to find out. I think I may go this route.